# Jquery I need the default value even when the value in the div tag changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have already raised a question regarding this but I didn't explain the scenario properly. So I wish to add the question again.

**HTML Code**

```
 <div class="cal-tbl text-center pzero col-xs-3">
     <br> <span>Calories</span></br>
     <h4 id = "calories"> 30 </h4>
 </div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
(function spinner(){
    $('#hitUp,#hitDown').click(function() {
        var spinnerVal = $('#demo_vertical2').val();//1 2 3
        var initCal  = parseInt($('#calories').text());
        var newCalories = parseInt($('#calories').text());
        var modifiedCalories = initCal * spinnerVal ;//30 60 90 //but output is 30 60 120
        $('#calories').html(modifiedCalories); 
    });
});
```

Here , I am using a spinner to increase and decrease values. If the value is 1 the values present inside the div tag should be 1 and if its two it should be 60 and again if I decrease to 1 it should become 30.

But according to my code what happens is when the value inside the spinner field is 1 its 30 and when its 2 its 60 and after that if I decrease to 1 it becomes 120 and If I increase to 2 again it becomes 240.

Kindly help me in sorting out I have wasted lot of time in this.

I ready to provide any necessary information if required.

Comment: I can't see a '30' anywhere in the HTML you've shown; are you sure you've posted the correct HTML?

Comment: @karthik - please make JSFiddle for more understanding

Comment: @DavidThomas In html there is th:text{}, there value 30 will be coming in html page while running in browser

Comment: And if you post the resulting HTML, not the templating script that generates it, it would clarify the question somewhat.

Comment: @David Thomas  Please see my updated question and give me some suggestions

Comment: @Prog Please see my updated question and give me some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using data attribute. It's simple and clear and jQuery has a powerful API to working with.

**HTML:**

```
<h4 id = "calories" th:text="${food.calories}" data-def-val="PutYourDefaultValueHere"> 309 </h4>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function spinner() {
    $('#hitUp,#hitDown').click(function () {
        var spinnerVal = $('#demo_vertical2').val();
        console.log(spinnerVal)


        var initCal = parseInt($('#calories').text());
        // var newCalories = parseInt($('#calories').text());
        var newCalories = $('#calories').data('defVal'); // there is no need to parseInt, since the jQuery will parse it when it's an int and is reading by data() method
        console.log(newCalories)
        var modifiedCalories = initCal;
        $('#calories').html(modifiedCalories);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I still would recommend you to use `$.data()` API:

Change your `HTML` as

```
<div class="cal-tbl text-center pzero col-xs-3">
    <br> <span>Calories</span></br>
    <h4 id = "calories" data-def-val="30"> 30 </h4>
</div>
```

and your script:

```
// (function spinner(){ // what is this about?
    $('#hitUp, #hitDown').click(function() {
        var spinnerVal = $('#demo_vertical2').val();//1 2 3

        var initCal  = $('#calories').data('defVal');
        // var newCalories = parseInt($('#calories').text()); // or this one?

        var modifiedCalories = initCal * spinnerVal ;//30 60 90
        $('#calories').html(modifiedCalories); 
    });
// }); // and this? you don't need them
```

Comment: @karthik and so do you

Comment: its worked but how to add dynamic values inside the data-def-value tag and solutions there

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way.

```
...
<h4 id = "calories" txt="309"> 309 </h4>
...
```

and after your code process, just do this

```
$('#calories').html($('#calories').attr("txt"));
```

=====OR=====

store on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calories").attr("txt",$("#calories").text());
});
```

and after process call following

```
$('#calories').html($('#calories').attr("txt"));
```

Hope this will help you